# dojo gfx - animate line getting longer

Tags: dojo, jquery-animate, line

I am wanting to animate a dojo gfx line getting longer.  (i.e to go from 10 pixels long to 100 pixels in length)
I have tried to use dojox.gfx.fx.animateTransform but have yet to figure out a solution.

Does anyone have a sample on how I can do this to assist me?

Thanks,

Drew

Comment: can you check out this [post](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/how-do-I-animate-a-line-getting-longer-td3704411.html).

Comment: I did check that out when i was first googling , but it did not help me.